# SQLLoader optional lines in a csv-file

Tags: database, oracle, sql-loader, controlfile

there are several csv-files which I have to put in a database via sqlloader.
The files look like this:

nr, value,description
839, 73, mydescription
842, 12, mydescription

But some lines in these files are optional and for these specific lines (839, 842) I have to put "null" in the corresponding field of the database if they do not exist in the file. (if they exist use the values and if not insert null)

Is it possible to specify this in the control file?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: You need use "TRAILING NULLCOLS" clause in your control file.  Look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917337/oracle-sqlldr-trailing-nullcols-required-but-why

Comment: Do you mean the value and/or description will not be present for those keys; or that the entire line including the keys will not be in the file?

Comment: The entire line will not be in the file...